# PHP - Add to cart button adds blanks to database

Tags: php, mysql, button, cart

In a webshop browsing page I am trying to make an "Add to cart" button, but when the button is pressed an empty field (containing only zeros in all rows) is just inserted in to the table "cart_items".

I would like the addtocart.php to insert all rows into the cart_items table.

This is the button code:

```
<form action="addtocart.php" method="post">
<td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.$id.'" /></td>
<td>
<div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Føj til kurv" /></div>
</td>
</form>
```

`$id` is defined as `$row['id']` previously in the document.

This is the addtocart.php code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not connect");  
mysql_select_db("comics") or die("could not find DB"); 
if(!is_numeric($_POST['id'])) { 

$eID=mysql_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    }

$addtocart="INSERT INTO cart_items SET id='".$eID."'"; 
mysql_query($addtocart);        
header("location:browsedata2.php"); 
exit; 
ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

I don't receive any errors, it just adds a blank.

I'm not sure I've given enough information here, if you need more just say so.

pls halp.

Comment: print your id and sql query before executing.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$_POST["id"]` is not numeric, it is a string. So `$eID` is never set.

Try this;

```
$eID=intval($_POST["id"]);
```

instead of ;

```
if(!is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
    $eID=mysql_escape_string($_POST['id']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are checking with `!is_numeric()` which will set `$eID` only if the `id` is not numeric. Try with -

```
if(is_numeric($_POST['id'])) { 
    $eID=mysql_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $addtocart="INSERT INTO cart_items SET id='".$eID."'"; 
    mysql_query($addtocart);
} else {
   // show some error if you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, this gives the correct id. But I am still missing the rest of the information in the other rows.

The table I get the data from contains seven rows, and so does the table I am inserting the data into. But only the row 'id' get a value (which is now correct, thanks to you). 

How do I insert the information from the remaining rows?

Comment: How are you inserting them?

Comment: Well. My thought was, that I am using the id to insert the whole item, but I suppose that's wrong then? 

I have been using this tutorial: 
http://www.webreference.com/programming/php/Shopping_03/index.html

Where he is doing something similar. I have skipped most security stuff, since this will be running on local. 

If I, for example, have a row called "price" that I need to insert also, how do I do this?